# Issue with EditText in Listview softkeyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a Listview with row layout contains two textviews and a edittext
In my activity i use

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"

and in edittext arguments are:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_quantity_test"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    ></EditText>
```

The problem : When i click on edittext the keyboard shows but edittext field lost focus and the keyboard type is alphabetic ,not numeric..
Thanks

That is main layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/img_back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/navigation_back" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tv_title_testing"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/test_title"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Medium"
    />
</RelativeLayout>

<Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/chronometer_testing"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"/>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.65"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/test_sub_title"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Medium" />

</LinearLayout>
<!-- <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"> -->
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >




            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lv_product_items_testing"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="9"
                transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" 
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />




        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/ll_conf"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_confirm_test_ok"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/test_conf" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_confirm_report"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/test_report" />
            </LinearLayout>   

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

First write down `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in Activity in Manifest file to set listview and Edittext and delete `android:inputType="numberSigned"` from Edittext is help to When you click EditText keyboard open with Alphabetic..

Comment: now when my keyboard shows the focus is up but when i'm on 3rd row and click next on soft keyboard soft focus move down but listview not scrolling down to show the row with edittext ..just stay hidden with positionated focus on the field

Comment: if click on switch button of device to turn of screen and push it again the row is visible while don't enter a key of softkeyboard ..when input a character the row again moves back..or justly sayed the listview moves up to first row

Comment: Are you use scrollview component in xml ?

Comment: I paste the source up ,I haven't Scrollview component

Comment: so please add Scrollview which you want to scroll part.is you want to scroll on list view so add scrollview on listview layout

Comment: Don't add all layout in scrollview but only add listview parent layout in scrollview

Comment: don't understand you, write me to psydef@gmail.com if wants to help for this issue

Comment: The problem occurs in my samsung galaxy s2 ..in other devices like tablet acer iconia with the same os and os version all is ok..