# The EditText in custom ListView often lost focus in Android 2.3.6

Tags: android

The EditText `android:id="@+id/adView"` works well.

The EditText `android:id="@+id/editnumber"` often lost focus when I switch Input setting.

For example, the focus will disappear when I change Input setting to handwriting.

**sms_step_list.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"  
    android:background="@drawable/border_ui"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >        


   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"    
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
        android:ems="10" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvTitle"    
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:textSize="16sp" /> 

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#DCDCDC"
        android:gravity="center"        
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBack"
            style="@style/myTextAppearance"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/BtnBack" />        

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNext"
            style="@style/myTextAppearance"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/BtnNext" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            style="@style/myTextAppearance"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/BtnCancel" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**sms_list_phone_number.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="left"    
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"    
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editnumber"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
            android:phoneNumber="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" >
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAddress"
            android:textSize="14sp"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
            android:text="@string/BtnAddressMin" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
            android:text="@string/BtnDeleteMin" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**StepList.java**

```
package ui;
import info.dodata.smsforward.R;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class StepList extends ListActivity{

    private ListNumberAdapter mListNumberAdapter=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sms_step_list);

        ListView lv=this.getListView();
        List<String> temp=new ArrayList<String>();
        temp.add("");

        mListNumberAdapter=new ListNumberAdapter(this,temp);    
        lv.setAdapter(mListNumberAdapter);  

    }

}
```

**ListNumberAdapter.java**

```
package ui;
import info.dodata.smsforward.R;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListNumberAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public final static int ForResult=50;

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<String> mListNumber;
    private Context mContext;

    public ListNumberAdapter(Context context, List<String> listNumber){
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);       
        mListNumber=listNumber;
        mContext=context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mListNumber.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.sms_list_phone_number, null);
            holder.tvContactName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvname);
            holder.editNumber = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editnumber);
            holder.btnAddress=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnAddress);
            holder.btnDelete=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        return convertView;
    }
}

class ViewHolder {
    int id;
    TextView tvContactName;
    EditText editNumber;
    Button btnAddress;
    Button btnDelete;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@ckpatel' answer for [Issue with EditText in Listview softkeyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860020/issue-with-edittext-in-listview-softkeyboard?rq=1) worked for me.

First write down android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in Activity in Manifest file to set listview and Edittext and delete android:inputType="numberSigned" from Edittext is help to When you click EditText keyboard open with Alphabetic..